# Aren't there several values for $abc$? I mean, it can't be a definite answer!

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is a problem from the National Mathematics Olympiad:

> There are three prime numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$; such that $a>b>c$ and $a-b-c=22$. What is the value of $abc$?

I've got more than one value for $abc$.

- Assuming that $a=31$, $b=7$, $c=2$, then $abc=434$
- Assuming that $a=37$, $b=13$, $c=2$, then $abc=962$
- Assuming that $a=47$, $b=23$, $c=2$, then $abc=2162$

and so on. Thus, I see that $abc$ can have more than one value. Please tell me if I misunderstood something about the problem.

Comment: I suppose it's worth asking:  $a-(b-c)$ or $(a-b)-c$?

Comment: It doesn't change much in both cases

Comment: Actually, the question didn't include any brackets.

Comment: National mathematics olympiad of which country?

Comment: @ami_ba of Egypt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am curious to hear which kind of math olympiads you are attending.

If $a>b>c>2$ then all of them are odd, so $a-b-c$ should be odd. This implies that $c=2$. Hence, we have to find all primes $a>b>2$ such that $a-b=24$, i.e., all odd primes $b$ such that $b+24$ is another prime. This is an [open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) as far as I know.

Comment: This is a nice, compact answer.

Comment: But the question doesn't ask if there are infinitely many such primes, only if the solution is unique (which it is not, since the OP found multiple solutions).

Comment: Yup! Almost the same methodology I've followed. And, it's the national math olympiad in Egypt, which is considered the first step prior to the regional and international ones.

Comment: @TobErnack Usually, if one asks in a math olympiad what is the value of $abc$, you should answer all its possible values (or prove there are none).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.